# Angular 5 @ts-ignore is not respected with npm start (ng serve)

Tags: angular, typescript, tsconfig

I have a constants file and some of the constants are not yet used by my app.

When I try to build or serve my Angular project I get :

> ERROR in src/app/shared/constants/app-constants.ts(6,14): error TS6133: 'LOCKED' is declared but never used.

If I add `// @ts-ignore` above the problematic line then my IDE correctly stops complaining about the unused constant.

However, `ng serve` still yields the same error.
The only way I can get ng serve to work is to add the following to **tsconfig.app.json**:

```
"noUnusedLocals": false
```

But this really irks me because now I'm not informed about unused variables that I might actually want to remove.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Why not comment out constants causing this issue until you need them?

Comment: can you try to do `/* tslint:disable:no-unused-locals */`before and same command just with enable afterwards. or you might need to use your spelling with camel case

Comment: @NicolasGehlert - unfortunately that doesn't work for me. I had previously tried tslint:disable which would disable all rules but that fails too.

Comment: @R.Richards - I also thought of that solution but would prefer to have the constants set up so that I can just go ahead and use them when I need them and not have to go backwards and forwards enabling them as required.